# PostgreSQL calculating average and standard deviation for hour of the day

Tags: postgresql, datetime, statistics

I have a collection of event data with timestamps and I want to know the average (arithmetic mean) hour of day these events occur and the standard deviation (in hours). The timestamps are in UTC timezone but the events are the result of user activity that might have occurred in a different timezone, e.g. UTC+12, and I don't know which.

This seems straight forward enough to do but due to the cyclical nature of 24 hour time it's not obvious. (For example 23 and 0 hours are close together in practice, but not mathematically.)

Here's an example:

Given these hours: `3, 4, 3, 0, 21, 23, 4`, the mean looks to be 8.3 and the standard deviation (population) 8.8. But if those events occurred in UTC+12 that would be incorrect as the "real" hours would be `15, 16, 15, 12, 9, 11, 16`, which gives a mean of 13.4, standard dev (pop) 2.6.

**What is the best way to calculate the correct mean (in UTC it would be 13.4) and stddev (pop) (2.6)?**

Example data (`events` table):

```
id |     timestamp
---+--------------------
1  | 2016-05-20 03:00:00
2  | 2016-05-20 04:00:00
3  | 2016-05-20 03:00:00
4  | 2016-05-20 00:00:00
5  | 2016-05-20 21:00:00
6  | 2016-05-20 23:00:00
7  | 2016-05-20 04:00:00
```

The PostgreSQL query I'm using right now is the following:

```
SELECT CAST(avg(extract(epoch FROM timestamp::TIME)) AS dec(18, 10)), 
       CAST(stddev_pop(extract(epoch FROM timestamp::TIME)) AS dec(18, 10)) 
FROM   events
```

Current result:

```
      Mean       |      Stddev   
-----------------+-----------------
29828.5714285714 | 31602.4282198023
```

(This is in seconds, this in hours is mean 8.3 and std dev 8.8.)

Expected result is mean ~13.4, std dev ~2.6.

Comment: Please show us db schema sample data and expected result. I see the example but not sure how is save on db.

Comment: I don't understand, is the expected result mean 13.4, standard dev 2.6 or is it mean 1.4, std dev 2.6?

Answer (score 1):

You can use AT TIME ZONE to convert the timezone.

```
SET TIME ZONE 'UTC';

WITH
test(id, dummy_time) as
(
values
(1, TIMESTAMP '2016-05-20 03:00:00'),
(2, TIMESTAMP '2016-05-20 04:00:00'),
(3, TIMESTAMP '2016-05-20 03:00:00'),
(4, TIMESTAMP '2016-05-20 00:00:00'),
(5, TIMESTAMP '2016-05-20 21:00:00'),
(6, TIMESTAMP '2016-05-20 23:00:00'),
(7, TIMESTAMP '2016-05-20 04:00:00')
)

SELECT      avg(date_part('HOUR', dummy_time AT TIME ZONE 'UTC+12')) as AVERAGE_HOUR,
            stddev_pop(date_part('HOUR', dummy_time AT TIME ZONE 'UTC+12')) as STDEV_HOUR

FROM        test
```

This gives the 13.4 mean and 2.6 stdev you are looking for.

Comment: This would be a good solution if I knew the timezone was UTC+12, but in practise I don't know which time zone (mentioned this in the first paragraph). One option is to check a couple of candidate timezones and use the best one but it seems like there should be a way to do this accurately.

Comment: In that case, I don't think I understand your setup. How will you check what timezone your values are coming from? A check would suggest that you already know what the real timezone should be. Seems to me that the root of the problem is the fact that the times are stored as timezone naive values, though I understand that fixing it might not always be straightforward.

Comment: In the most basic terms I have a set of times, all in UTC, and I want to know the average and stddev hour of the day for those times. The problem is that the times originated in different timezones, and because time is circular (23 is close to 0), it's not straight forward to just treat them like integers. I hope this makes sense?

Comment: I don't think it makes sense to calculate the average of a circular range. And if you can't get an average, then you can't calculate standard deviation. What is the average of 1am today, 11pm today and 1am tomorrow? Are the two 1am's treated as equivalents?

Comment: Perhaps you mean that the difference between 11pm tonight and 1am tomorrow is 2 and not 22? So you want the lowest value of the difference between two ways of calculating time difference?